# JPA: Parent changes not reflected when querying a child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entites `X`and `Y`defined as follows. `Y` has a many to one relationship with `X`:

```
public class X {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "xId", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

And

```
public class Y {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "yId", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="x", nullable=false)
    private X x;
    ...
}
```

When I update an entity `X`, the changes are not reflected correctly when I load `Y`. Assume theres already a row on the X table with the values (1, "2222"). Printing Y the first time will show X as (1, "2222"). However after the commit I see the X table at the DB has changed, but Y i still linked to the old version of X when queried again:

```
Y y = yDao.findById(ABC);
System.out.println(y);  // y.x.description is "2222"

xDao.beginTransaction();
X x = new X(1, "4444");
xDao.update(x);
xDao.commitTransaction();   

Y y2 = yDao.findById(ABC);  // y.x.description is still "2222" instead of "4444"
System.out.println(y2);
```

My conclusion is Y is being retrieved from the cache the second time. What am I missing in order to make Y be aware that X has changed?

In short, y is equal to y2, meaning my second find is retrieving its info from cache?

What am I missing in order to make Y be aware that X has changed?

Adding output sql:

```
Hibernate: // first findById()
    select
        y0_.yId as yId12_1_,
        y0_.address as address12_1_,
        y0_.x as x12_1_,
        x1_.xId as xId17_0_,
        x1_.description as descript2_17_0_ 
    from
        daoTest.Y y0_ 
    inner join
        daoTest.X x1_ 
            on y0_.x=x1_.xId 
    where
        y0_.yId=?
Y [id=11, x=X [id=1, description=0000]]   // System.out
Hibernate: // merge(x)
    select
        x0_.xId as xId5_0_,
        x0_.description as descript2_5_0_ 
    from
        daoTest.X x0_ 
    where
        x0_.xId=?
Hibernate: // commitTransaction()
    update
        daoTest.X 
    set
        description=? 
    where
        xId=?
Y [id=11, x=X [id=1, description=0000]]   //System.out, theres no select again
```

GenericDAO class

```
public class GenericDAOImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements
GenericDAO<T, ID> {

private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (em == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "EntityManager has not been set on DAO before usage");           
    } else {        
        return em;
    }
}

public void refresh(T entity) {
    this.getEntityManager().refresh(entity);
}
...
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you assign the new x-object to the y-object. I think i don get what you want.

Comment: What if you also use transactions when reading? Does a manual `EntityManager.refresh` of `y` update `x` correctly?

Comment: I want Y to pick the new values on X when I query for it. This is just an example. My point is someone else on a totally different place can do update(x) and I'll still obtain the old X value attached to my new Y

Comment: refresh() had no effect, both with transaction or not

Comment: appreciated the editing, did'nt thought of adding comemnts in code :)

Comment: Are you sure that `y` reference instance of `x`with id=1 ? That is, the update of `x` update the correct row and does not insert a new one?

Comment: I'm sure, the table has only 1 row all the time. Added the generated SQL from hibernate

Comment: How do you obtain the entity manager in each DAO? Also, are you using the 2nd level cache?

Comment: XDAO xDao = new XDAO(); XDAO extends GenericDAO. For which I assume each DAO has its own EntityManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your DAO has one `EntityManagerFactory` and one `EntityManager`. I would suggest to make the `EntityManagerFactory` `static`. This way all entity managers come from the same factory. Maybe the problem is related to 2nd-level cache.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and replies, Yes I confirmed the problem is the pattern itself which create 2 separate DAOs. It works with one unique entityManager and without refreshing or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use EntityManager.flush() method after updated your record.

Here is the difference between flush and refresh method.

```
      entityManager.flush();
// Calling this flush method will synchronize the database with the values
// taken from the entity object.

     entityManager.refresh();
// The refresh() method will refresh the entity object with the values taken from the database.
// All the updates that are done are lost.
```

Comment: When you commit the transaction, it flushes the changes automatically. As per the SQL log, the update does take place already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is normal and expected behavior. Hibernate has a first-level cache (the Session), and once some entity is loaded in the first-level cache, every time you get a reference to this entity, the values from the first-level cache will be retrieved.

You can refresh the state of the entity in the cache by calling EntityManager.refresh() (or Session.refresh()). Note that even if you do that, you might still get the old state of the entity if the isolation level of your transaction is REPEATABLE_READ.

Comment: refresh has no effect, could it be because each DAO has a separate entityManager?

Comment: Have you refreshed the X entity? Or just Y?